# shell script [[:not found

Tags: bash, shell

when i execute the script it gives error as [[: not found

6.txt file has following values 1.7\n 1.8\n 1.5\n1.4\n 1.9\n 33.5

```
#! /bin/bash 
INPUT=6.txt while read a ; do

 x="$a"
 echo value of x : $x
 if [[ $a >= 1.7  ]];
  then
       echo "test passed"
 else
        echo "test failed"
       # echo else block a :$a
 fi
done<"$INPUT"
```

Error

```
./test3.sh
value of x : 1.7 ./test3.sh: 18: [[: not found test failed value of x : 1.8 ./test3.sh: 18: [[: not found test failed value of x : 1.5 ./test3.sh: 18: [[: not found test failed value of x : 1.4 ./test3.sh: 18: [[: not found test failed value of x : 1.9 ./test3.sh: 18: [[: not found test failed value of x : 33.5 ./test3.sh: 18: [[: not found test failed
```

i am using busybox tiny version of unix

BusyBox v1.01 (2021.12.29-16:10+0000) Built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

kinldy help me to solve this error

Comment: `ash` is not `bash`

Comment: `awk '{ print "test " ($1 >= 1.7 ? "passed" : "failed") }' 6.txt`

Answer (score 1):

`[[` is a feature of the [KornShell (`ksh`)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell). You are using the [Almquist Shell (`ash`)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell), more precisely, [Busybox](https://busybox.net/)'s fork of `dash`, [the Debian Almquist Shell](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash_(shell)), which does not have this feature.

More precisely, in BusyBox support for `[[` is *optional* and controlled by a compile-time option. You have compiled your BusyBox without support for `[[`. If you want to use `[[` in BusyBox, you need to [configure](https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#configure) and re-compile it with support for `[[`.

Comment: Got it thanks. i will check

Comment: can you help me to provide the correct document for syntax. i have given single square bracket build successfully

Comment: suppose if i need to add a relational operator in the IF condition, need a document to follow syntax. kindly provide me the link for docuemnt

Comment: If you have a question, please post a question, not a comment. However, note that asking for resources, documents, links, etc. is off-topic. That's what search engines are for.

Answer (score 1):

`[[` is present in bash, ksh and zsh, not in POSIX shell, but even then, you can not do comparision with floats within `[[ ... ]]`. At least zsh has float arithmetic, if you do it properly. I suggest to change your script to

```
if (( a >= 1.7 ))
```

and execute the script by

```
zsh test3.sh
```

At least this error should go away.

Comment: The Korn shell also supports real (floating) numbers.